# magento-cloud did not properly create files in app/etc and Magento 2 cannot instantiate

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento2 cloud pro setup. I have created a local development environment according to the instructions on [Local environment setup](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/access-acct/first-time-setup.html)

**My Setup**

Ubuntu 18.04 server, Nginx, PHP FPM 7.1 - From andre ppa, MariaDB

My local dev is a VM created a few weeks ago and up until yesterday it was working fine. I also yesterday made a copy from scratch of the same setup on physical hardware to do the migration from 1x to 2x.

When I build the environment with the new server using `magento-cloud` tool, the command **`magento-cloud` build** created a new symlink to `_www` which did not get created on my VM environment. It also did not create any file in `app/etc` directory. On my VM environment the files were created. Today I deleted the Magento2 folder on my VM box and it did the same behavior as the physical hardware. No files were created in `app/etc` directory, but previously it worked without issue.

Can anyone confirm this issue?

The result of the files not created produces the error:

> [2018-07-12 04:02:44] INFO: Output: array (   0 => 'PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Framework\Config\CacheInterface in
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50',
>   1 => 'Stack trace:',   2 => '#0
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create(\'Magento\\Framewo...\')',
>   3 => '#1
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get(\'Magento\\Framewo...\')',
>   4 => '#2
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
>   \'Magento\\Framewo...\', NULL, \'cache\',
>   \'Magento\\Framewo...\')',   5 => '#3
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime(\'Magento\\Framewo...\',
>   Array, Array)',   6 => '#4 /home/magento/m in
>   /home/magento/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 50', ) [2018-07-12 04:02:44] CRITICAL: Command php bin/magento
>   module:enable --all returned code 255

When the execution of **`magento-cloud` build** is done for the first time, it completes 100% without error, creates the Magento folder structure, etc. If I do nothing, make no file changes and do the same exact command again, it fails because of the missing files.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Before running command magento-cloud build, need to run composer update, this is what creates the files. Not sure if this step is in the documentation or not.